# Help with $\lim_{x\to \infty}{\sin{1\over x}\over {1\over x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Given the problem:

> $\lim_{x\to \infty} x\sin({1\over x})$

I am confused as to how to obtain the given answer of $1$. My steps are as follows: First I moved the $x$ to the denominator to become

> $\lim_{x\to \infty}{\sin{1\over x}\over {1\over x}}$
>
> Next, I set ${1\over x}$ equal to $u$ to get $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ of ${{\sin (u) \over u}}$

However, I am unsure how to proceed. Plugging in infinity seems to be the logical step, but I am still unsure if that would yield anything helpful. Any advice would be appreciated.

> Note: I would like to just forwarn that I am a high school junior just starting AP Calc BC so I am sorry if my question seems a bit trivial

Comment: You'll have to change the limit to something involving $u$.  As $x\to \infty$, to what does $u$ tend?

Comment: @Bye_World I am unsure how to answer this. I know that the limit as ${u\to \0} of that would be 1, but I am unsure how to manipulate the step I left off at  in order to resemble this.

Comment: You define $u$ by $u=\frac 1x$.  Then take the limit.  As $x\to \infty$ we have $u\to 0^+$.  Thus, doing the change of coordinates: $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)}{\frac 1x} = \lim_{u\to 0^+} \frac{\sin(u)}{u}$$ which as you've rightly said is [equal to $1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1).

Comment: @Bye_World thank you so much. I was initially confused as to how you were able to go from finding the limit as x approaches infinity to finding the limit as u approaches zero but I believe I understand it now. I would mark your comments as the answer if it were possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set

$$x\to \frac{1}{y}$$

Hence

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sin y}{y} = 1$$

Comment: It should actually be $y\to 0^+$, i.e. from the positive side.

Comment: Right! Thanks! I'll leave the comment without editing, so people can read!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than change variables, one can simply recall from elementary geometry ([SEE THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1/2046827#2046827))for $|\theta|\le \pi/2$, we have

> $$\theta\cos(\theta)\le\sin(\theta)\le \theta \tag 1$$

Using $(1)$ with $\theta =1/x$ for $x>0$ reveals

$$\cos(1/x)\le \frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}\le 1 \tag 2$$

Applying the squeeze theorem and exploiting the continuity of the cosine function yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}=1$$

Comment: This is how the limit $\dfrac {\sin \theta}{\theta} \to 1$ is often proved.

Comment: @gfaucpass Yes, I know.  But the inequalities in $(1)$ can facilitate a broad range of limits.  -Mark